# json encode breaking for large strings

Tags: php, xml, json

I am trying to `json encode` an well-formed XML string into a SimpleXMLElement object. But what happens is that, it `breaks` or `exit`.

I tried with small `xml` files and works fine and the issue is with large `xml` files

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$directory = "lookup.xml";
$xmlContent = file_get_contents($directory); // get contents of lookup
print_r(simplexml_load_string($xmlContent));
$arrayXml = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlContent)),TRUE);
print_r($arrayXml);
```

`lookup.xml` files :

```
1. lookup.xml - 2 MB (works fine)
2. lookup.xml - 13 MB (Not working)
```

Is it because of a large file or some string breaking??

Comment: thats why that way is not really perfect at all. why not traverse it normally?

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1048576 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12286130 bytes). And now I solved the issue by `ini_set('memory_limit', '100M');`

Answer (score 0):

What are exactly error messages, loading 13Mb into XML than into JSON will take lot of memory, what is memory limit on your server. With your code I have tried XML sitemap of 7.5 MB and 
memory_get_peak_usage() at the end of script showed 119MB usage for 13 it would be almost twice depending on XML itself.